# Loopback return an existing record on PU/UPSERT

Tags: postgresql, loopbackjs, upsert

I have the following PostGreSQL Locations table:

```
--------------------
| ID | Name        |
--------------------
| 1  | Kitchen     |
--------------------
| 2  | Bedroom1    |
--------------------
```

ID is a sequential PQ and Name has a unique constraint.

Locations.json Name property has

```
"index": {
    "unique": true
 },
```

And Locations.js includes `Location.validatesUniquenessOf('Name');`

If I run a `PUT` against `Locations` with JSON { `"Name":"Kitchen" }` I get a 422 validation error, which is fine, but ideally I'd get the existing Kitchen record (or at least the ID) at the same time. Can I do this in the loopback framework with one REST call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extend your API with custom remote method and then use findOrCreate method on your model to return found or created instance as a response.

http://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Remote+methods#Remotemethods-Howtodefinearemotemethod

http://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/PersistedModel+class;#persistedmodel-findorcreate

```
Location.findOrCreate(
  {where: {"name": "Kitchen"}},
  data,
  function(err, instance){
    if (err){
      console.log(err);
    }
    console.log(instance); //this will be your found or created instace based on query
  });
```

Comment: Thanks @A.Z. This returns the full object if it already exists in the database, but not if it is added. Is there a way of returning the newly inserted record with its new ID field?

Comment: Hi conradj... I have tried this method myself, it always returns id (found or created). Documentation says it returns instance if found, but it always returns instance.

Comment: It does work - loopback seems to wants all models and properties to be lower case otherwise things stop working. Thank you!